# Windows Command Line: 'not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line

When I run cmd in Windows 7 (by typing `'cmd'` in Windows Run), the following error shows:

[image]

> '-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

I have tried checking PATH in environment variables.
Running `echo %PATH%` gives me the following:

> C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\xampp\php;

I have checked all the directories being pointed to by PATH. Everything seems to be in place. What I can not understand is where `'-p'` is being called. I'm thinking that it has something to do with `cmd` since it only comes out when I call `cmd` and not when I run `ipconfig` or `ping`, for example.

Comment: How do you run 'cmd'? Do you execute a shortcut or type 'cmd' in the search box?

Comment: @Simon, I run it using Windows Run. I updated the question.

Comment: check each of the directories listed there in your PATH, for cmd.* - perhaps that will provide a clue

Comment: This guy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077689/r-cmd-on-windows-7-error-r-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-comm had a space before a ; in the path statement.

Comment: @edelwater Slightly different case there; that guy was *trying* to run a program called `R`, which should have been in his path but was not, due to that mistake. This case is of the command processor (`cmd`) itself raising the error on start - and the start was successful. Still, the problem that caused it might be the same; I won't discount that...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's possible that you have an 'AutoRun' command set in the registry. There's two registry keys, one per-user and one per-computer, that can define commands that are run every time the command processor (`cmd.exe`) is started. They're actually listed in `cmd /?`.

Anyway, try running `cmd /d` and see if that produces the same message. The `/d` flag means "don't run AutoRun commands", which makes it perfect for testing this.

The registry values are:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
```

Check both. By default, neither should exist. You may wish to fix the command strings in yours, or even delete them entirely.

Related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx

---

Alternatively, you could have a batch script or similar set up with the name `cmd`, which is being executed instead of the native `cmd`. Try the command `where cmd` to print out a list of `cmd`s in your path, in order of execution. If there are any other than/before the one in `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, you may wish to delete them, or remove their path from your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I tried executing `cmd /d` and as expected, the problem was gone. I then checked the registry, and I found `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` some command strings with regards to ANSICON. I was not able to remove it the last time I deleted it. I simply removed the key! This is a brilliant answer!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, for people now sure how to edit the registry keys in windows, see this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-open-registry-editor-in-windows-10-deab38e6-91d6-e0aa-4b7c-8878d9e07b11. Rather straightforward.

Comment: Ah, the good old times of actually being able to solve problems. Whatever happened to that?