# Open CMD and it immediately crashes

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

When I open `cmd` (through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or from `system32` folder) in Windows 10, it seems to be running a code (`mode 20,5`) and after a while, it kills itself.

Same problem happens when I try to execute `.bat` file.

Anyone will know how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: I bet it's because you have a cmd autorun defined (i.e. a command that runs every time you launch cmd). See here: https://superuser.com/a/571717/117590 and let us know if that's the cause/solution.

Comment: how about the cmd.exe in sysWOW64?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Thanks it worked. Seems like the autorun registry is from a malware.

Comment: @Bob Thanks for the link. It is just the autorun registry wasted a lot of time!